# Trouble using the requests package python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to get a basic web scraping script running just to test some things out and I noticed a lot of people recommending the "requests" package so I downloaded it but I am getting some weird responses and I'm hoping someone could help me interpret them as I am very new to python

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.python.org')
r.content
```

and the output is this:

```
C:\Python32\python.exe "D:/Code Testing/Missing Time/webscraper.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Code Testing/Missing Time/webscraper.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\requests-2.11.1-py3.2.egg\requests\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\requests-2.11.1-py3.2.egg\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from . import idna
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\requests-2.11.1-py3.2.egg\requests\packages\idna\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import *
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\requests-2.11.1-py3.2.egg\requests\packages\idna\core.py", line 10
_unicode_dots_re = re.compile(u'[\u002e\u3002\uff0e\uff61]')
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: How did you install requests ?

Comment: downloaded the zip for github and ran setup.py

Answer (score 0):

The requests module, version 2.11.1, doesn't support Python 3.2 - see the end of [their PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/2.11.1). You have a few options:

- Best, if you control your desktop, is to install a newer version of Python.
- If you can't do that, and don't have the wherewithal to get a newer version of python installed for you, you could try using an older version of requests. Going off the tags on PyPI, [1.0.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/1.0.0) claims to supported Python 3.2 but the [2.0.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/2.0.0) version doesn't.
- Use a different library. This would be unfortunate, as requests really is an excellent HTTP library.

There are some *very real* downsides to running old versions of libraries, namely missing features and the possibility of **security vunerabilities**. This is not a theoretical possibility - see [this CVE](http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=2014-1829) for example. For more details, see requests [vulnerability disclosure page](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/community/vulnerabilities).